# Use more than one or in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sequelize.js, where-clause

I want to write a little bit complex `where` in sequelize using 3 or condition.

SQL `where` example:

```
where 
(c1 = 'a' or c2 = 'b' or c3 = 'c' or c4 = 'd') 
and (c5 = 'e' or c6 = 'f' or c7 = 'g' or c8 = 'h') 
and (c9 = 'i' or c10 = 'j')
```

In sequlelize I wrote something like this:

```
where: {
  $and: {
    $or: [{ c1: 'a' }, { c2: 'b' }, { c3: 'c' }, { c4: 'd' }]
  },
  $or: [{ c5: 'e' }, { c6: 'f' }, { c7: 'g' }, { c8: 'h' }]
}
```

but how can I add this object: `$or: [{ c9: 'i' }, { c10: 'j' }]`?

P.S. Don't worry in project I use `Op`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an outer `$and` property with the terms of the inner parts.

```
where: {
    $and: [
        {
            $or: [
                { c1: 'a' }, { c2: 'b' }, { c3: 'c' }, { c4: 'd' }
            ]
        },
        {
            $or: [
                { c5: 'e' }, { c6: 'f' }, { c7: 'g' }, { c8: 'h' }
            ]
        },
        {
            $or: [
                { c9: 'i' }, { c10: 'j' }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```